# extract beta, sd and P-value from meta-regression using meta package in r to a nice output

Tags: r, regression, meta

I am using the code below to do meta-regression in `R` and repeat it several time for different variables.
My dataframe and codes are as follow

```
data<-read.table(text="Studlab  PCI.total.FU    CABG.total.FU   PCI CABG Mean.Age   Females..
             A  4515    4485    45  51  65.1    22.35
             B  4740    4785    74  49  65.95   23.15
             C  3621.4  3598.6  41  31  63.15   28.65
             D  2337    2314.2  20  29  60      30.5
             E  1835.2  1835.2  20  16  66.2    22
             F  2014.8  2033.2  11  6   64.45   28.55
             G  1125    1125    4   5   61.95   20.65
             H  1500    1500    6   3   62.25   23.5
             I  976     1000    11  3   61.5    21
             J  202     194     10  0   62.4    1", sep="", header=T)

 library(meta);library(metafor)
 mr <- metainc( PCI, PCI.total.FU,CABG, CABG.total.FU,
              data = data, studlab = Studlab, method = "Inverse")
```

## Then for meta-regression I used the following code

```
MEG<-metareg (mr, ~Mean.Age);MEG ; 
#==================================
b = round(MEG[["b"]], digits = 2)
se = round(MEG[["se"]], digits = 2)
pval = round(MEG[["pval"]], digits = 2)
paste0(b,"±",se,", P=",pval)
# Then I repeat meta-regression with another variable 
MEG<-metareg (mr, ~Females..);MEG
#==================================
b = round(MEG[["b"]], digits = 2)
se = round(MEG[["se"]], digits = 2)
pval = round(MEG[["pval"]], digits = 2)
paste0(b,"±",se,", P=",pval)
```

## and so on. So; b,se, pval and paste0 steps will be repeated frequently to get the needed output

The content of `MEG` is shown in the screenshot below.

My question is there is anyway to repeat this function (those repeated steps) several times with different variables (here I used "Mean.Age" then I used "Females..".  In another term , I reproduce several MEG with different variables. **I am thinking if there is anyway like Macro or so to call those function repeatedly without continuous copy and paste the code several times**

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.
[image]

I am doing that to finally create a table like this

[image]

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data, all necessary code, and a clear explanation of what you're trying to do and what hasn't worked. Even if it were easy to read the data out of that screenshot, we couldn't run any code on it

Comment: @camille Thanks for your comment. I edited my question and upvote your comment. I hope to get an answer to  my question. Appreciate any input.